# View not updating from directive functionality

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am attempting to sort some data from an API in a table. I know that the functionality all works when I had it all in a controller, but now I am separating this concern out to a directive, as I believe I should, and this is where I am having some trouble.

Through a series of `console.log`'s I am able to see that all the functionality seems to be working, and when a header is clicked, the new set of data is returned as I would expect. It's just not updating the view with the refreshed data once the table header is clicked.

I have tried fiddling around with `apply()` and `watch()`, but nothing is working for me yet.

Here's a trimmed down version of my directive:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('sortOrder', [
    '$routeParams',
    'GetData',
    'SortData', 
    function($routeParams, GetData, SortData) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            controller: function() {
                console.log("Sortable");
                // Set this to a variable self to avoid closure issues
                var self = this;

                // Set the module declared endpoint to a variable
                self.endpoint = $routeParams.endpoint;

                // Initially set the column sorting to Ascending
                self.sortOrder = "ASC";

                self.setOrder = function (column) {
                    console.log("Setting order");

                    GetData.getData(self.endpoint, "&orderBy[" + column + "]=" + self.sortOrder).then(function(data){
                        console.log("Fetching");
                        self.presentData = SortData.sortData(self.endpoint, data);
                        console.log(data);
                    });
                });
             },
             controllerAs: 'sort'
          };
}]);
```

I get all the correct `console.log`'s of `Sortable`, `Setting order`, `Fetching` & the data object.

As you can see it calls in 2 services for getting the data and presenting the data, they are a bit too massive to be putting in here, but here's part of my HTML where the header is clicked:

```
<thead data-sort-order>
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="header in display.headers" class="{{ header }}" ng-click="sort.setOrder(header)"><span>{{ header }}</span></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

I hope that will make sense. Let me know if there's anything else you may need.

Many thanks in advance!

**EDIT =====**

Here's some of the HTML to present the data to be refreshed as requested:

```
<tr ng-repeat="entries in display.presentData" class="table-row">
    <!-- Using (key, details) also allows access to the key of each object value -->
    <td ng-repeat="(key,details) in entries track by $index" class="{{ key }}">{{ details }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: try using `sort.presentData` instead of `display.presentData`. I'm not sure of the position of your HTML but you either need to change the variable name or make a two-way binding between your controller's `presentData` and your directive's `presentData`, in the 2nd case it requires a more complicated answer

Comment: Something is missing : either specify a template in your directive. Or use scope inheritance in order to inject new variable like ng-repeat do with $index

Comment: Thanks @valepu, but changing to `sort.presentData` didn't fix the issue. So I think it might be more complicated 2nd option.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that there's no relation between your directive and the `presentData` array. Normally you would pass the presentData array as parameter for your directive, creating a two-way binding. This way every change to the variable inside the directive would be passed to the variable inside your controller. It's not necessary but it would be nice to also create a template with the `thead` part and create a tag directive, but that's not in the scope of the answer

You should be able to solve it this way, but to have a 100% correct answer one needs to know the correct structure of your code (it won't work if the directive is not inside your controller):

```
<thead data-sort-order data-present-data="display.presentData">
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="header in display.headers" class="{{ header }}" ng-click="sort.setOrder(header)"><span>{{ header }}</span></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Then in your directive:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('sortOrder', [
    '$routeParams',
    'GetData',
    'SortData', 
    function($routeParams, GetData, SortData) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                presentData: "="
            }
            controller: function() {
                console.log("Sortable");
                // Set this to a variable self to avoid closure issues
                var sort = this;

                // Set the module declared endpoint to a variable
                sort.endpoint = $routeParams.endpoint;

                // Initially set the column sorting to Ascending
                sort.sortOrder = "ASC";

                sort.setOrder = function (column) {
                    console.log("Setting order");

                    GetData.getData(sort.endpoint, "&orderBy[" + column + "]=" + sort.sortOrder).then(function(data){
                        console.log("Fetching");
                        sort.presentData = SortData.sortData(sort.endpoint, data);
                        console.log(data);
                    });
                });
             },
             controllerAs: 'sort',
             bindToController: true
          };
}]);
```